# Write to command line if application is executed from cmd

Tags: c#, console, cmd

I searched the web and Stackoverflow, I didn't find anything. 
I am sorry if this question already exists.

If my C# application is called through the cmd for example:

> C:\System32\MyConsoleApplication -parmOne -paramTwo ...

Is there a way to write into the cmd (for example to giving progressinformation?)

Edit: Cause I use a Consoleapplication the solution ist `Console.WriteLine` It doesnt worked for me cause my application requires adminrights (trough a Manifestfile) and was called with normal userrights. In this case the UAC asks for rights and opens a new Cmd with the application.

Comment: Read about `Console.WriteLine` method. http://www.dotnetperls.com/console-writeline

Comment: This was the first Thing i tried, but this shows another console and do not write into the calling cmd...

Comment: nonsense. Could you  please bring some screenshots to show your case? Two screenshots would be enough. Console output shouldn't create another windows\processes.

Comment: Im sorry, you are absolutly right. It was cause of the Application.Manifest file, which requires adminrights. Because it was called with normal rights the UAC asked for admin rights and a new admincmd opened...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This all depends on what the `exe` type is - which is a flag in the PE-header (the "exe" shell):

- if it is flagged as a windows app, it doesn't get a console / output to the existing console - regardless of how it is started
- if it is flagged as a console app, it ***does*** get a console / output to the existing console - regardless of how it is started

It cannot be both. It you want it to work like a windows exe normally, then you will have to compile it as a windows exe, which means no: it won't write to the console normally. Trying to acquire access to the console from a windows exe is tricky, and would require P/Invoke to the OS.

If it *is* flagged as a console exe, then just `Console.WriteLine` will work fine.

Answer (score 13):

better solution : http://www.nerdyhearn.com/blog/157/

here is the code of the site:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern bool AttachConsole(int dwProcessId);
private const int ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS = -1;

[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  // Enable visual elements just like always
  Application.EnableVisualStyles();
  Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

  // Attach to the parent process via AttachConsole SDK call
  AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS);   // <-- important point here
  Console.WriteLine("This is from the main program");

  Application.Run(new Form1());
}
```

You can use the `AttachConsole` call at your will in the special conditions you need. This is much better and flexible and does not require you to change your application manifest. if its a win32 app, wll good for your app. if its launched from a cmd then the output will appear as excpected.

My opinion: this is just some useless microsoft complication of some concepts that are so pure and natural in the Unix world. If your application is launched from a visual launcher (icon, nautilus..) then the output is lost. You can launch your app from a console and its gets in the console. you can redirect the output if you need, it all imbricates logically and its powerful. With microsoft... its bloated and gets in the way of everybody.

Comment: Great solution thanks. But to anyone like me that didn't realise the DLLImport bit goes INSIDE the Program class declaration. Otherwise you get a lot of unhelpful compilation errors!